# coding a search bar with icon inside it

Tags: html, css

I am trying to code the following layout. I have messed up the code and not sure what's the best way to do it.

[image]

```
<div class="search-wrapper">
        <form action="search.php" method="get" name="search">
          <div class="search-box"><img class="search-icon" src="images/search-icon.png" width="21" height="18" alt="search icon" />
            <input name="seach" type="text" value="Search for dishes or restaurants" />
          </div>
          <input class="submit-button" name="Go" type="submit" />
        </form>
      </div>



#search {
    height:125px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.search-wrapper {
    width:465px;
    height:45px;
    background-color:#f0f0f0;
    margin:43px auto 0;
    border:1px solid #e9e9e9;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; /* FF1+ */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* Saf3-4 */
    border-radius: 5px; /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Saf5, Chrome */
    position:relative;
}
.search-box {
    width:375px;
    height:32px;
    background-color:#fff;
    margin:5px 7px;
    border:1px solid #cfcfcf;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; /* FF1+ */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* Saf3-4 */
    border-radius: 5px; /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Saf5, Chrome */
    position:relative;
}
.search-box img.search-icon {
    margin:8px 0 0 5px;
}
.search-box input {
    border:none;
    height:30px;
    width:332px;
    margin:0;
    position:absolute;
    font-size:16px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
}
input.submit-button {
    background:url(../images/go-button.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:none;
    height:32px;
    width:68px;
    position:absolute;
    top:6px;
    left:390px;
    cursor:pointer;
 //right:15px;
}
```

Here is the code @ paste bin:

http://pastebin.com/KQR3mPiW

Images:

http://bayimg.com/IAPcpAACi

http://bayimg.com/JapcBaAci

Comment: Try up-loading the relevant images somewhere that they cab be hot-linked (I recommend http//bayimg.com, since they also allow you to specify a removal code and, obviously, let you remove them). As it is, your css works well enough (though it seems verbose), it's just the submit button that needs to be done.

Comment: added the image links :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here yo go: http://jsfiddle.net/SjafT/

**Preview:**

[image]

You might change the value of 'readjust in jsfiddle' part.

Comment: :( why have u cut the image and re-done it ? here is the image http://image.bayimg.com/iapcpaaci.jpg  the code is so simple not like mine :) just wondering about image

Comment: just because jpeg is not transparent

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use

```
position: absolute;
```

? 
Use

```
position: relative; float: left;
```

with the search box 
and the same with the button. 
No margin specification would be required either.